# Overloading Functions with std::forward Forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I would like to know if it is possible to do forwarding with some constraints on types so that overloading can be automatic. For example, suppose I have the following base function:

```
int f(A a, B b)
{
    return g(a) + h(b);
}
```

where `A` and `B` are classes that contain all the proper copy and move constructors, and `g` and `h` are functions each of which has two overloads: `int g(const A&)`, `int g(A&&)`, and the same for `h`. The usual way to forward `a` and `b` in `f` would be

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
int f(T1&& a, T2&& b)
{
    return g(std::forward<T1>(a)) + h(std::forward<T2>(b));
}
```

However, I would like to also add another way to use this function:

```
int f(B b, A a)
{
    return g(a) + h(b);
}
```

If I try to use forwarding with this overload, the resulting template function would like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
int f(T1&& b, T2&& a)
{
    return g(std::forward<T1>(a)) + h(std::forward<T2>(b));
}
```

which will collide with the first template.

So my question is, when I write a template function for forwarding, can I constrain `T1` and `T2` so that in the first overload, `T1` can only bind to `const A&` and `A&&`, while the second overload can be triggered if `T1` is `const B&` or `B&&`?

Without such mechanism, I would need to write 8 overloads explicitly.

*Note: I think I might be able to do something (somewhat nasty) with some templates from `type_traits` in this toy example, but I would like to know first if there is an easier way because in reality, overloads can be more different than in this toy example.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can I constraint T1 and T2 so that in the first overload, T1 can only bind to `const A&` and `A&&`?

Yes. The concept is known as SFINAE (Substituation Failure Is Not An Error) and basically would look like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<A, std::decay_t<T1>>::value>* = nullptr
          >
int f(T1&& a, T2&& b);
```

If `T1` does not "decay" to `A`, then the `enable_if_t<>` type would be ill-formed, and this overload would be thrown out.

If that's too verbose, you can write an alias:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
using enable_if_decays = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<To, std::decay_t<From>>::value>;

 template <typename T1, typename T2,
           enable_if_decays<T1, A>* = nullptr>
 int f1(T1&& a, T2&& b);

 template <typename T1, typename T2,
           enable_if_decays<T1, B>* = nullptr>
 int f1(T1&& b, T2&& a);

 // etc.
```

Comment: Does this prevent me from making another overload?

Comment: I thought it was implicit. I will add it then.

Comment: @Tunococ There's nothing preventing you from making another overload - you just have to make sure it wouldn't be ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you. This is nicer than I had expected. It seems to me that this situation comes up pretty often so I will probably add this to my library :)

Answer (score 1):

An other possibilities is to retrieve the correct parameter according to its type

something like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
int f(T1&& t1, T2&& t2)
{
    auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(t1, t2);
    return g(my_get<A>(t)) + h(my_get<B>(t));
}
```

with `my_get<T>` similar to `std::get<T>(TUPLE&)` but retrieve `T&&` or `T&` depending of tuple content type.

Comment: +1 for nice scaling in a case of increasing number of arguments. Unfortunately, will not work when some of arguments has the same type.

Comment: @NikkiChumakov: we can still do a `my_get<I, T>` to retrieve the `i`th `T` in tuple.

Comment: I was able to create my_get<Index,Type> implementation that copies the elements on return:  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lWtHqXgEyVrB4y8v But I was unable to implement the perfect forwarding in it, depending on T1,T2 types. Imagine the function "h(int& i) {...}" and we have std::tuple<int&, int const&, int&&> at the input. my_get<1, int> should probably return the reference not to the middle element, but to the last tuple's element. But it turns out to be too difficult for me to implement it in that way.

Comment: @NikkiChumakov: nearly correct, your return `T` instead of the correct type in your `get` function. Using `decltype(auto)` helps: [Demo](https://ideone.com/VYEVbA)